# Selecting value of active select with jQuery

Tags: jquery

In a viw I have 5-15 dynamically created dropdowns like this:

```
<select class="task-type" id="21">
   <option value=""></option>
   <option value="easy">easy</option>
   <option value="hard">hard</option>
</select>
```

Where class `task-type` is used for every dropdown and `id` is unique for each an every and represents a record in a database, so they vary from 1 to 10000.

I then have the following jQuery code to try to pick the value of a dropdown that has changed its value:

```
$( '.task-type-select' ).change(function(){
    alert($( ".task-type-select option:selected" ).text());
});
```

However, it alerts every dropdown's value, where what I need is only the currently changed one.

Any help or guidance is much appreciated.

Comment: You want the jQuery to compare and alert the options that change over time, not the ones the client selects, correct?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use the `this` keyword to reference the element which raised the event. From there you can use the `val()` method to get the selected value:

```
$('.task-type-select').change(function(){
    console.log($(this).val());
});
```

Answer (score 5):

Use `$(this)` / `this` to refer the current select instead of using `.task-type-select`

```
alert($(this).find("option:selected" ).text());
```

Since *text* and *value* is same in your case you can use `.value` or `.val()` instead of going long way to get selected option text

```
 alert(this.value);
```

Answer (score 1):

Select has class "task-type", but in JQ you use '.task-type-select'.

This example is work:

HTML:

```
<select class="task-type" id="21">
   <option value="123">qweqwe</option>
   <option value="easy">ea1sy</option>
   <option value="hard">ha1rd</option>
</select>
```

and jQ:

```
$(document).ready(function(){

$( '.task-type' ).change(function(){
    alert($( ".task-type option:checked" ).text());
});
})
```